# Fixing cracked door trim piece?

Tags: body-work, acura, interior, tsx

[image]
What's the best way to fix this? Is there some specific adhesive that is going to hold up well on that type of plastic? It's a 1st gen Acura TSX, and the seatbelt got stuck when closing the door resulting in that crack.

More pics here https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jsE8.jpg

Comment: With duct tape of a similar colour?

Answer (score 3):

[This is what I use for plastics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0044FBB8C)

There other brands and types but this is specifically the best I have found for the price.

[There is better but pricey.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004QXPNH2)

Pull the door panel for best results. Clean both parts to be joined with alcohol and let dry.

Mix an appropriate amount of epoxy, while it is thin, butter both halves you want to join but don't assemble yet, let it set up for 15 minutes, then assemble and hold with good tape. It will set overnight. The next day gently pull off the tape and mix more epoxy and 
liberally apply it along the crack on the inside (outside too if you don't mind the look) and let set over night.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix it is to replace it. You may find a match at a salvage yard.